# What are best practices for exporting variables passed from the server to HTML so that they can be used in javascript modules?

Tags: javascript, html, build, webpack, babeljs

Let's say I'm serving up a web application and my server is passing an object to the front-end that looks like this:

```
{
   user_name : "Robert",
   user_settings : {/*some settings object*/}
}
```

If I want to access this information in, say, main.js, in the past I've just made this information global in my html file. (e.g.):

```
<html>

    <head>
      <title>Example Page</title>
    <!-- style links would go here -->
    </head>

    <body>

    <!-- script tags would go here -->

        <script>
           window.server_json = {
               user_name : "Robert",
               user_settings : {/*some settings object*/}
           }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This really doesn't seem to fit into the way that we're writing javascript these days with webpack and babel. I would like to be able to export that object and use it in other files while avoiding globals.

I'm not sure how to go about this, but I envision it would looks something like:

(Example.html)

```
<html>

    <head>
      <title>Example Page</title>
    <!-- style links would go here -->
    </head>

    <body>

    <!-- script tags would go here -->

        <script>
           export default json = {
               user_name : "Robert",
               user_settings : {/*some settings object*/}
           }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Main.js)

```
import json from "./Example.html";
//Do something with the data received from the server
```

In my current project, I'm using webpack, babel, and vue.js. I've been searching for some way to do this for a few hours now, and would appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the data would be sent from the server using PHP and the slim framework. It would look something like this:

```
$app->get('my/page', function($request, $response){
    return $this->view->render($response, 'my_page.html', [
        "user_name" => "Robert",
        "user_settings" => [/*some settings object*/]
    ]);
});
```

Comment: how the server is passing data to the front end? can't js just get the data without going through html?

Comment: I'll update the question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) plugin to request the data from the server. You can use [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to cache the data on the client.

Comment: Wouldn't it be significantly less efficient to load the page and then make another call to load the data?

Comment: The first time you visit the page there are two requests, the result of the data request should be cached. The client cache should always be checked before requesting data from the server. Memoization is the practice of caching the result of a function/request to improve performance.